# svn client doesn't work after upgrading to 1.7: working copy is too old

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I was using VisualSVN client and server on local machine + MS Visual Studio for a while.

Today I decided to upgrade tortoisesvn to the latest version (because it popups every time that never version is available).

After that I can not commit/browse history etc. from VS. tortoisesvn reports such error:

`Working copy "C:\pathtorepository" is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6).`

How to fix my problem? Should I rollback tortoisesvn from 1.7 to 1.6?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `svn upgrade` ( added in 1.7) to upgrade your working copy.

Or Right click on the folder in Explorer -> Choose `SVN Upgrade working copy`

http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html

You will also have to update VisualSVN to 2.5.1 - http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes/

Comment: tried that, now VS thinks that solution is not under svn, because I see menu "Add Solution to Subversion..." :(

Comment: If you have been using 1.5/1.6 until now, and installed 1.7.7, you are out of luck when it comes to TortoiseSVN, the contextmenu item is actually gone.
But, make sure you install TortoiseSvn with the commandline tools, then it's easy to do the above tip, "svn upgrade" at the commandline. 
Why they removed the contextmenu is beyond me though.

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this question because composer update failed with this message.  I think what happened is svn updated since I ran `composer install`.  All I had to do is delete the `vendor` folder and run `composer install` again.