# Issue with VisualSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I use VisualSVN Server 2.6 which uses svn version 1.8. I have TortoiseSVN client 1.7. 
When I do a `svn info`, it throws the below error:

```
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: The working copy at 'F:\XMS\xmsWorkspace\1.0.00'
is too old (format 29) to work with client version '1.8.0 (r1490375)' (expects f
ormat 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.
```

Can you please let me know, if VisualSVN Server is backward compatible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [svn client doesn't work after upgrading to 1.7: working copy is too old](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014425/svn-client-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-1-7-working-copy-is-too-old)

Answer (score 2):

You've upgraded VisualSVN Server to 2.6 / SVN 1.8, so your command-line svn.exe client expects upgraded SVN 1.8 working copies.

Apache Subversion 1.8 [requires you to `svn upgrade` your older working copies to newer format](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#wc-upgrade). SVN 1.8 can't work with older WCs and prompts you to upgrade a working copy located at "F:\XMS\xmsWorkspace\1.0.00". See [`svn upgrade` command-line reference](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/upgrade/).

I suggest you to upgrade TortoiseSVN to the latest version as well, and upgrade your working copies. Don't forget to restart the computer after upgrading TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0):

Go in your project directory and delete the .svn directories and try again.